# What is the proper way of Seach working on Magento 2.3?

Tags: search, magento2

I've got a question with Search on default engine - MySQL

There are products in searching results which have the following coincidences:

1. Product headings.
2. Product description.
3. Product category name (it the name of the category connected to searching query)
4. Product headings at Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells under the product card description.
5. Product headings at Configurable products under the product card description.

Is everything ok? Or the last two cases are out of results should be?